# Marking or Tagging Non-structured Data

Tags: macos, extract, text-extraction

I'm not entirely sure how to term this, but I've searched several phrases and haven't found what I need.

I have a whole lot of unstructured data that I need to get into a database. I used to do the heavy lifting with Needlebase and just clean up the data from there. But now that it's no more, I'm want for a good way to quickly grab pieces of text beyond select, copy, paste, lather, rinse, repeat.

Ideally something where I could select some text and a popup asks what it is (from a user-defined list, title, start time, image path, etc.) and then marks it as such. Naturally I would need to be able to mark the beginning and end of a record (all row data is consecutive, just not in an easily parseable format).

I could probably write something in a few hours that would do this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something exists. I'm on OS X, but I'd be interested in software for any platform.

Comment: They have a few alternative programs suggested on their website: http://needlebase.com/

Comment: @AminoAcid Yeah, but all of those (unless I'm missing something) are for dealing with already structured, if messy, data.

Answer (score 0):

is your data in HTML format? if yes you can use Jsoup